# Bounding integral of the form $\int_0^\infty |z+x|^{-n}dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I need to bound a sum of the form $\sum_{j=1}^m |z+j|^{-n}$ with $\Re z\ge1$ and $n \ge 2$. I am searching for a bound of the form 
$$\sum_{j=1}^m |z+j|^{-n} \le C |z|^{-n+1}.$$

It is easy to see that

$$\sum_{j=1}^m |z+j|^{-n} \le \int_{0}^{m+1} |z+x|^{-n}dx \le \int_{0}^{\infty} |z+x|^{-n}dx.$$

My problem is that I cannot compute the integral. By setting $z=r+i s$, we have
$$\int_0^\infty ((r+x)^2+s^2)^{-\frac n2} dx.$$

My idea was to use integration by parts to transform it to an integrable form, but so far I cannot find how I am going to do that. Any help is welcome.

Comment: Should it not be $r+x$ rather than $r-x$?

Comment: Yes Ron, you are right. I got used to write that because in my case  I actually have $\Re z<-1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $(r+x)^2 + s^2 \geq (r+x)^2$. Hence, we have
$$\int_0^{\infty} \dfrac{dx}{((r+x)^2 + s^2)^{n/2}} \leq \int_0^{\infty} \dfrac{dx}{(r+x)^n} = \dfrac{r^{-n+1}}{n-1} < r^{-n+1}$$
We also have $(r+x)^2 + s^2 \geq x^2+s^2$. Hence, we have
\begin{align}
\int_0^{\infty} \dfrac{dx}{((r+x)^2 + s^2)^{n/2}} & \leq \int_0^{\infty} \dfrac{dx}{(x^2+s^2)^{n/2}} = \int_0^{\pi/2} \dfrac{\vert s \vert \sec^2(t) dt}{\vert s \vert^n \sec^n(t)}\\
& = \vert s \vert^{-n+1} \int_0^{\pi/2} \cos^{n-2}(t)dt < \vert s \vert^{-n+1} \dfrac{\pi}2
\end{align}
Hence, we have (make use of the fact that $\vert r \vert + \vert s \vert \leq 2 \vert z\vert$)
$$\int_0^{\infty} \dfrac{dx}{((r+x)^2 + s^2)^{n/2}} \leq C \vert z \vert^{-n+1}$$

Comment: Wow! This is an amazing and elegant solution! Thank you!

Comment: By the way, I didn't see how $|r|+|s|\le 2 |z|$ helps here, so I used the equivalence of the norms on the plane to derive the result.

Comment: @rom While proving the equivalence of norm, we will need to make use of the fact that $\vert r \vert + \vert s \vert \leq 2 \vert z \vert$, i.e., if we add both the inequalities I have, we will get that the integral is less than $\dfrac{C(\vert r \vert + \vert s \vert)}2$ and use the fact that $\vert r \vert + \vert s \vert \leq 2 \vert z \vert$ to conclude what you want.

Comment: I don't see what you mean. We get the bound $\frac{C}{2}(|r|^{1-n}+|s|^{1-n})$, which complicates things a bit. I just moved $|r|^{1-n}$ and $|s|^{1-n}$ on the LHS and then I added the inequalities. This gives $|t|_{n-1}^{n-1}\int dx\le C$. Then by the norm equivalence we can translate it to an inequality with $|t|_2$.

Comment: @rom However, you like it. Both are the same. In your case, you say that you can use norm equivalence, but what I have given is a proof for one half of norm equivalence, namely $\vert z \vert_1 \leq 2 \vert z \vert_2$.

Comment: Ah, yes. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{{\rm e}^{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert #1 \right\vert}$
$\large\it\mbox{Hint:}$

$\large n > 1:$

> \begin{align}
> {\cal T}_{n}
> &=
> \int_{0}^{\infty}{\dd x \over \bracks{\pars{r + x}^2 + s^{2}}^{n/2}}
> =
> {n \over 2}\int_{0}^{\infty}
> {x\bracks{2\pars{r + x}} \over \bracks{\pars{r + x}^2 + s^{2}}^{n/2 + 1}}\,\dd x
> \\[3mm]&=
> n\int_{0}^{\infty}
> {\bracks{\pars{r + x}^{2} + s^{2}} - \bracks{r\pars{r + x} + s^{2}} \over \bracks{\pars{r + x}^2 + s^{2}}^{n/2 + 1}}\,\dd x
> \\[3mm]&=
> n\int_{0}^{\infty}\!\!\!\!\!\!
> {\dd x \over \bracks{\pars{r + x}^2 + s^{2}}^{n/2}}\,
> +
> \left.r\,
> {1 \over \bracks{\pars{r + x}^2 + s^{2}}^{n/2}}\right\vert_{0}^{\infty}
> -
> ns^{2}\int_{0}^{\infty}\!\!\!\!\!
> {\dd x \over \bracks{\pars{r + x}^2 + s^{2}}^{n/2 + 1}}\,
> \\[3mm]&=
> n{\cal T}{n}
> -
> {r \over \bracks{r^2 + s^{2}}^{n/2}}
> -
> ns^{2}{\cal T}_{n + 2}
> \end{align}

> \begin{align}
> {\cal T}_{n + 2}
> &\equiv
> {1 \over s^{2}}\,{n - 1 \over n}\,{\cal T}_{n}
> -
> {r \over n s^{2}}\,{1 \over \pars{r^{2} + s^{2}}^{n/2}}
> \\[3mm]
> {\cal T}_{2}
> &=
> \int_{0}^{\infty}{\dd x \over \pars{r + x}^{2} + s^{2}}
> =
> {1 \over \verts{s}}\,\bracks{{\pi \over 2} - \arctan\pars{r \over \verts{s}}}
> \\[3mm]
> {\cal T}_{3}
> &=
> \int_{0}^{\infty}{\dd x \over \bracks{\pars{r + x}^{2} + s^{2}}^{3/2}}
> =
> {1 \over s^{2}}\,\pars{1 - {r \over \sqrt{r^{2} + s^{2}\,}\,}}
> \end{align}